# Can NSXMLParser Be Use To Parse HTML

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsxmlparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an NSXMLParser to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866376/using-an-nsxmlparser-to-parse-html)

I have used `NSXMLParser` to parse xml files and RSS feeds. What i am confused about is that whether `NSXMLParser` is only for xml or can we use it to parse html as well. From a little searching on the Internet, i am assuming that some people use it for parsing html.

But are there any limitations or disadvantages of using `NSXMLParser` with html ?

Comment: (X)HTML is XML, so yeah it'll work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you HTML document is well formed xhtml, then it will work. As a guess, you will not be working with well formed xhtml, as it's rare in the real world.

HTML (including HTML 4 and 5) is not well formed XML and will not be successfully parsed by an XML parser.

Consider the following sample:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Sample Document</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Sample Document</h1>
<P>This document will <strong><em>fail</strong></em> as XML.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In the above document, content-type is not in quotes (`<META http-equiv=content-type …`), `<H1>` and `</h1>` are different cases, `<P>` does not have an end tag, and `strong` and `em` are not nested correctly. This is valid HTML but invalid XML.